# Can't create graph tables with sqlproj

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

After getting really fed up with using hierarchyids to manage my node tree, I decided to take a stab at using SQL Server 2017's graph functionality to ease my troubles.

I have a little bit of confusion, though. Currently, all of my SQL scripts are stored and organized in a SQL database project. When I create a node table and publish it to my Azure SQL Database, it only creates a standard table.

However, I can paste the exact same query into SSMS and it creates the graph table just fine. I've included the query below. Am I missing anything obvious?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GraphSite]
(
    [SiteId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
        [SiteName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [SiteTypeId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [SiteTimeZone] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT N'America/New_York',
    [SiteStatusId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [SiteThemeId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_GraphSite] PRIMARY KEY ([SiteId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_GraphSite_SiteType] FOREIGN KEY ([SiteTypeId]) REFERENCES [SiteType]([SiteTypeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_GraphSite_SiteStatus] FOREIGN KEY ([SiteStatusId]) REFERENCES [SiteStatus]([SiteStatusId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_GraphSite_SiteTheme] FOREIGN KEY ([SiteThemeId]) REFERENCES [SiteTheme]([SiteThemeId])
) AS NODE;
```

EDIT: I installed SQL Server 2017 locally and it leaves "AS NODE;" in fine. So SSDT seems to have an issue building graph tables to Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. Which is weird, considering Azure SQL databases fully support graph tables. Any thoughts?

Comment: I noticed that when I publish to a SQL script instead of directly to the server, it actually **removes** the "AS NODE;" portion at the bottom.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try downloading the latest version of SSDT from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

This should fix the problem for you.